# show last 100 lines textArea AS3 Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, textarea, chat

I have a very busy chat app and the textArea is set to clear itself after certain amount of text, but what I want is to show the last 100 lines of text in the textArea and remove the rest.

*Using Flash CC*

**The text comes from a Red5 Server like this:**

```
function onReceiveMsg(UserName:String, Msg:String):void{
  if (myTextArea.length > 21400){
    myTextArea.htmlText = "";
  }

   //add text to textArea
   myTextArea.htmlText += "<font color='#FF0000'>"+UserName+": "+Msg"</font>";

}
```

So, any idea to maintain the last 100 lines of chat?  Thanks!  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply store all the messages you receive in an array:

```
var messages:Array = [];

function onReceiveMsg(userName:String, msg:String):void
{
    messages.push({ userName: userName, msg: msg });
    displayMessages(); // See below.
}
```

And pull the last 0-100 items from that for display:

```
function displayMessages():void
{
    myTextArea.htmlText = "";

    var recent:Array = messages.slice(-100);
    for each(var i:Object in recent)
    {
        myTextArea.htmlText += "<font color='#FF0000'>" + i.userName + ": " + i.msg + "</font>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but then the new text comes on top of the textArea instead, new messages should be at the bottom ...

Comment: ok I fixed thata by removing the reverse part, now the problem is that when there are 100 lines the new messages won't show up, just the first 100 lines and it won't show any new messages at all ...

Comment: @Alex `reverse().slice(0, 100).reverse()` might be what you're after.

Comment: var recent:Array = messages.slice(0, 100); did the job, but when the array has 100 messages, it won't add a new one and it won't remove the oldest one.

Comment: @Alex Sorry, try `.slice(-100)` without any `reverse()`.

Comment: This works! `var recent:Array = messages.slice(-100);

if(messages.length >= 100){
 messages.splice(0, 1)
}`

Thanks a lot @Marty !!!